# How NOT to print emojis from comments or submission when using praw

Tags: python, praw

Getting error messages when I am trying to print out comments or submission with emojis in it. How can I just disregard and print only letters and numbers?

Using Praw to webscrape

```
top_posts2 = page.top(limit = 25)
for post in top_posts2:
   outputFile.write(post.title)
   outputFile.write('   ')
   outputFile.write(str(post.score))
   outputFile.write('\n')
   outputFile.write(post.selftext)
   outputFile.write('\n')

   submissions = reddit.submission(id = post.id)

   comment_page = submissions.comments
   top_comment = comment_page[0] #by default, this will be the best comment of the post

   commentBody = top_comment.body

   outputFile.write(top_comment.body)
   outputFile.write('\n')
```

I want to output only letters and numbers. and maybe some special characters (or all)

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple ways you can do this. I would recommend creating kind of a "text cleaning" function

```py
def cleanText(text):
    new_text = ""
    for c in text:       # for each character in the text
        if c.isalnum():  # check if it is either a letter or number (alphanumeric)
            new_text += c
    return new_text
```

or if you want to include specific non-alphanumeric numbers

```py
def cleanText(text):
    valid_symbols = "!@#$%^&*()"    # <-- add whatever symbols you want here
    new_text = ""
    for c in text:       # for each character in the text
        if c.isalnum() or c in valid_symbols:  # check if alphanumeric or a valid symbol
            new_text += c
    return new_text
```

so then in your script you can do something like

```py
commentBody = cleanText(top_comment.body)
```